# Unit Test to Cover VF Controller

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller

I have a custom VF controller.  I have written a unit test that covers much of it, however, I am not able to cover the page re-direct upon save in my controller (lines 33-37).  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

**Controller:**

```
//Controller for Deal Summary
public class VF_DealSummaryController{

public List<Deal_Summary__c> DS {get; set;}

    private final Opportunity opp;
    public VF_DealSummaryController(ApexPages.StandardController myController){
        DS = new List<Deal_Summary__c>();
        opp=(Opportunity)myController.getrecord();
    }

    public Deal_Summary__c DS2 = new Deal_Summary__c();
        public void DealSummary(){

            DS2.Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
            DS2.Legal_Name__c = opp.Account.Id;
            DS.add(DS2);
        }

    public PageReference save() {

        Boolean error=false;

        IF(DS2.Agreement_Effective_Date__c == null){
            DS2.Agreement_Effective_Date__c.addError('You must enter an estimated Effective Date.');
            error = true;
        }
        IF(DS2.Net_Payment_Term_Days__c == null){
            DS2.Net_Payment_Term_Days__c.addError('You must enter the Net Payment terms.');
            error = true;
        }
        IF (error) {return null;}
    insert DS;
        {
        PageReference RetPage = new PageReference('/apex/DealSummaryViewTest?id=' + DS[0].id + '#RTF');
        RetPage.setRedirect(true);
        return RetPage; 
       }
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@Istest
private class TestDealSummController
{
    static testMethod void testMyController1()
    {    
        Account acct1 = TestCreateRecords.createAcct(0);
        insert acct1;

        Opportunity opp1 = TestCreateRecords.createOppNew(acct1.Id);
        insert opp1;

        Deal_Summary__c DS1 = new Deal_Summary__c();
            DS1.Opportunity__c = opp1.Id;
            DS1.Legal_Name__c = opp1.AccountId;
            DS1.Agreement_Effective_Date__c = date.newinstance(2025,1,31);
            DS1.Net_Payment_Term_Days__c = 30;

        ApexPages.StandardController DealSumm1 = new ApexPages.standardController(opp1);
        VF_DealSummaryController DealSummCont1 = new VF_DealSummaryController(DealSumm1);
        DealSummCont1.DS.add(DS1);
        DealSummCont1.DealSummary();
        DealSummCont1.save();

            DealSummCont1.DS2.Net_Payment_Term_Days__c = 30;
        DealSummCont1.save();

            DealSummCont1.DS2.Net_Payment_Term_Days__c = 50;
        DealSummCont1.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are lines 33-37?

Comment: Everything from "Insert DS" down in my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is missing:

```
DealSummCont1.DS2.Agreement_Effective_Date__c = Date.today();
```

so the controller line:

```
IF (error) {return null;}
```

means the code after that never runs in your test case.

Comment: I don't understand.  I do have a value set in my test for Agreement_Effective_Date__c, why would it not get past the controller line you specified?

Comment: It is th DS2 reference you need to set and at present you are setting the other field twice on DS2.

Comment: Thanks.  So are you saying that I need to set values on the DS2 reference that will bypass the validations in my controller?